# How should you write junit test cases for multiple implementation of the same interface?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Before asking question, let me explain the current setup:

I have an service interface, say Service, and one implementation, say ServiceImpl. This ServiceImpl uses some other services. All the services are loaded as bean by spring.

Now, I want to write junit test cases for the ServiceImpl. For the same, I use the applicationContext to get the Service bean and then call different methods on it to test them.

All looks fine for the public methods but how do I write test cases for private methods? Because we might not have the same private methods for different implementations?

Can anyone help me here on what should be preferred way of writing test cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUnit - How to test all classes that implement a particular interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003/nunit-how-to-test-all-classes-that-implement-a-particular-interface)

Answer (score 5):

The purist answer is that private methods are called that for a reason! ;-)

Turn the question around: given only the specification of a (publicly-accessible) interface, how would you lay out your test plan before writing the code? That interface describes the expected *behavior* of an object that implements it; if it isn't testable at that level, then there's something wrong with the design.

For example, if we're a transportation company, we might have these (pseudo-coded) interfaces:

```
CapitalAsset {
    Money getPurchaseCost();
    Money getCurrentValue();
    Date  whenPurchased();
    ...
}

PeopleMover {
    Weight getVehicleWeight();
    int    getPersonCapacitly();
    int    getMilesOnFullTank();
    Money  getCostPerPersonMileFullyLoaded(Money fuelPerGallon);
    ...
}
```

and might have classes including these:

```
Bus implements CapitalAsset, PeopleMover {
    Account getCurrentAdvertiser() {...}
    boolean getArticulated() {...}
    ...
}

Computer implements CapitalAsset {
    boolean isRacked() {...}
    ...
}

Van implements CapitalAsset, PeopleMover {
    boolean getWheelchairEnabled() {...}
    ...
}
```

When designing the `CapitalAsset` concept and interface, we should have come to agreement with the finance guys as to how *any* instance of `CapitalAsset` should behave. We would write tests against `CapitalAsset` that depend *only* on that agreement; we should be able to run those tests on `Bus`, `Computer`, and `Van` alike, without any dependence on which concrete class was involved. Likewise for `PeopleMover`.

If we need to test something about a `Bus` that is independent from the general contract for `CapitalAsset` and `PeopleMover` then we need separate bus tests.

If a specific concrete class has public methods that are so complex that TDD and/or BDD can't cleanly express their expected behavior, then, again, that's a clue that something is wrong. If there are private "helper" methods in a concrete class, they should be there for a specific reason; it should be possible to ask the question "If this helper had a defect, what public behavior would be affected (and how)?"

For legitimate, inherent complexity (i.e. which comes from the problem domain), it may be appropriate for a class to have private instances of helper *classes* which take on responsibility for specific concepts. In that case, the helper class should be testable on its own.

A good rule of thumb is:

> If it's too complicated to test, it's too complicated!

Answer (score 4):

Private methods should be exercised through the public interface of a class. If you have multiple implementations of the same interface, I'd write test classes for each implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have written multiple implementations of an interface and want to test all implementations with the same JUnit4-test. In the following you will see how you can do this.

Also there is an example that shows how to get a new instance for each test case.

Example Code
Before I start explaining things here’s some example code for the `java.util.list` interface:

```
public class ListTest {

  private List<Integer> list;

    public ListTest(List<Integer> list){
      this.list = list;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getParameters() {
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { new ArrayList<Integer>() },
        { new LinkedList<Integer>()}
      });
    }

    @Test
    public void addTest(){
      list.add(3);
      assertEquals(1, list.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split the testcases.

First you test the class which is calling the different implementations of the interfaces. This would mean you are testing the public methodes.

After this you test the interface implementaion classes in another testcase. Their you can call the methode with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting article on how to test private methods with JUNIT at http://www.artima.com/suiterunner/privateP.html

So, I assume we should prefer testing private methods indirectly by testing the public methods. Only in exceptional circumstances, we should think of testing private methods.

Comment: That article is **horrible**.  Approach 1 is the only valid answer - yet somehow the author insists he agrees with the advice not to test private methods but does it anyway.

Either his utility methods should be moved into their own class and made public, or they're tested by existing class tests.

Comment: @dtsazza: I agree that approach 1 is probably the best way. But, you should give credit to the author to try out different approaches and came up with a good article for the same. Also, by doing so, he proves a point that approach 1 is probably the best.